# A function to automatically move to a directory that changes daily

Tags: zsh, directory, function

I have decided that I want to have a directory that is my working directory that changes daily. When I write notes or articles, I want to be able to create a shell function that if I create an alias called "work", it will move me to the date.

For instance, I have a directory called 2017, and in this directory I have 12 directories {01-Jan,02-Feb,03-Mar,04-Apr,05-May,06-Jun,07-Jul,08-Aug,09-Sep,10-Oct,11-Nov,12-Dec}, and each month has directories 01-{28,30,31}.

Is there way to move me to my work directory automatically? I am using Zsh under Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

(Note, I am doing this in Bash, not Zsh)

With that directory structure, you ought to be able to do this:

```
alias work="cd $HOME/Desktop/$(date +%Y/%m-%b/%d)"
```

Testing:

```
pwd
/Users/maulinglawns
work
pwd
/Users/maulinglawns/Desktop/2017/01-Jan/10
```

Answer (score 0):

add `alias` to your `.zshrc` file:

```
alias today-dir='cd $(date +"%Y/%m-%b/%m-%d")'
```

You should add full path to `2017` before `$(date...)` part (eg. `cd ~/notes/$(date ..`) to be able to call command from any current working directory.